# Laravel 5.4 with mongodb 3.2 -- Failed to parse mongodb URI

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, laravel

```
/*  local.ERROR: MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Failed to 
    parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb://:/'. Invalid host string in URI. in 
    D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel_bdna\bdna\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Client.php:84
```

I had printed the mongodb URI IN LOG FILE

```
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.INFO: 111111111111111111111111111111111111111  
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.INFO: mongodb://maddyUser:Moji6251@localhost:27017/mad  
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.INFO: 111111111111111111111111111111111111111  
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.INFO: mongodb://maddyUser:Moji6251@localhost:27017/mad  
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.INFO: 111111111111111111111111111111111111111  
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.INFO: mongodb://maddyUser:Moji6251@localhost:27017/mad  
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.INFO: 111111111111111111111111111111111111111  
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.INFO: mongodb://maddyUser:Moji6251@localhost:27017/mad  
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.INFO: 111111111111111111111111111111111111111  
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.INFO: mongodb://:/  
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.INFO: 111111111111111111111111111111111111111  
    [2017-11-28 02:35:16] local.ERROR: MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Failed to parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb://:/'. Invalid host string in URI. in D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel_bdna\bdna\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Client.php:84

    #0 D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel_bdna\bdna\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Client.php(84): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->__construct('mongodb://:/', Array, Array)
    #1 D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel_bdna\bdna\app\MongoBG\MongoBG.php(109): MongoDB\Client->__construct('mongodb://:/', Array, Array)
    #2 D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel_bdna\bdna\app\Providers\MongoBGServiceProvider.php(68): App\MongoBG\MongoBG->__construct('mongodb://:/', Array, Array)*/
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure, I will come back with a good formatted question! Thanks!

Comment: It's not only about formatting. You did not even ask a question.

Comment: How do you're using MongoDB? Did you installed `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` or the `mongodb/mongodb`? Also, swap `mongodb://:/` (which is an invalid schema) to `mongodb://`

Comment: installed mongodb using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb.. swap mongodb://:/ (which is an invalid schema) --- swap means.. can you please explain

Comment: I am working on laravel with mongodb as backend, its working fine.. but frequently it shows an Internal Sever Error. I had checked the log. It seems there is a problem with parsing mongodb URI, But it works when refresh! and then not working ... Give your Suggesstions Please!

Comment: @felipsmartins... Thank you for your Consideration on this... have you noticed that .. here the mongodb uri string is logged as mongodb://maddyUser:Moji6251@localhost:27017/mad .. these credentials I gave in database.php .... but at sometime or second time .. the string logged as mongodb://:/  ...

Comment: @R.Madhanbabu hmm... it sounds like a library bug. However I've running Larave5.4 + Jensegers package without any problem so it is so weird... Well, can you share your database.php config (clear password before, of course)?

Comment: Also, what the heck is `App\MongoBG\MongoBG` supposed to be? It seems `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` is not being provided.

Comment: 'mongodb' => [
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE','mad'),
            'host'     => $hosts,
            'port'     => $port,
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME','maddyUser'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD','Moji6251'),
            'options' => [
                // Database to use for authentication
                'database' => env('DB_AUTH_SOURCE', env('DB_DATABASE', 'mad')),
                'ssl' => env('DB_USE_SSL', false),
               // 'connecttimeoutms' => 30000,
            ]
        ],